# N-Queens exercice the iterative way with a stack is quite a mess. Java

Tags: java, algorithm, n-queens

I was solving some programming exercises in java. Everything was perfectly fine until my mind kind of froze a bit on the N Queens exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is something wrong with the thing that is returned by s.get(x)? Since

```
s.showAll()
```

says that there is stuff in the stack, it is strange that

```
(s.get(x)==y)
```

is always false. You could try inserting:

```
for (int x=1; x<=boardSize; x++){
    for (int y=1; y<=boardSize; y++){
        System.out.println("(" + x + ", " + y + "): " + s.get(x) + " == " + y + " -> " + (s.get(x) == y));
    }
}
```

at the end, to check whether the results of s.get(x) agrees with s.showAll().

The rest of the code here looks fine.

Comment: It was my mistake in the stack function get, thanks for your help, i fixed it now. Got an exception now but will fix it, right away.